# Function returning true regardless of input

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am having a nightmare trying to work out why this function is always returning true no matter what the input. The doc in question is a JSON file. I have put it into the variable test, and the outcome always appears to be true, regardless of what 'test_type' is:

```js
var doc = {
  "test_type": "test3"
};

var ignore = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

test = (ignore.some(function(v) {
  return doc.test_type.toLowerCase().indexOf(v) == -1;
}));
console.log('Test:', test);
```

However, if I use the code below instead it will only return true if the 'test_type' value is in the 'ignore' array. So this will return false.

```js
var doc = {
  "test_type": "test4"
};

var ignore = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

test = (ignore.some(function(v) {
  return doc.test_type.toLowerCase().indexOf(v) >= 0;
}));

console.log('Test:', test);
```

What I want to do is check if test_type matches a value in the array, or more accurately if a string from the array can be found as a substring within the test_type array, and if so then exclude the doc from the output.

Comment: I am positively confused about what you *do* want and why neither of those snippets are working for you…

Comment: Maybe you need to lower case the array elements, `return doc.test_type.toLowerCase().indexOf(v.toLowerCase) >= 0`

Comment: Your second function works right. `some()` would  return `true` if any element meets the condition. That is why your first function always return `true`.

Comment: If you are interested in the opposite of what you now get in `test`, then just negate the expression with `!`: `test = !ignore.some(function(v) { ... });`

Answer (score 1):

The `test_type` property is not an array but a simple string. You should then not use `indexOf` but simply iterate over your array and check if it matches the `test_type` value

```js
var doc = {
  "test_type": "test3 test5"
};

var array1 = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']; // true
var array2 = ['test1', 'test2', 'test4']; // false

var docTestTypes = doc.test_type.split(" ");

var test1 = array1.some(function(elem, index, array) {
  return docTestTypes.indexOf(elem.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
});

var test2 = array2.some(function(elem, index, array) {
  return docTestTypes.indexOf(elem.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
});

console.log("test 1 : " + test1);
console.log("test 2 : " + test2);
```

Comment: if he's hellbent on using indexOf, it could work by using:

    return array1.indexOf(elem.toLowerCase()) != -1;

Comment: @FvB You code is wrong. You are checking if the element that you are iterating over is in the array you are iterating... This will always be true. However `indexOf` is really not necessary

Comment: Sorry, what I didn't make clear is that the JSON could contain, for example, "test3 test". But I still want it to identify if any of the values from the array can be found in "test_type". So "test3 test" would still return true.

Comment: @hoskarl No problem ! Dont forget to mark it as the answer if it is the case

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, the semantics of

```
ignore.some(function(v)
            { 
                return doc.test_type.toLowerCase().indexOf(v) == -1;
            });
```

would be to check whether ignore contains an element which does not occur in `test_type`, which would be the case for your call.